# Use Expression in app.config

Tags: vb.net, expression, app-config

I have a user setting that I have added on the Settings page under the project's Properties:

[image]

What I would like to do is set the default value to an expression pointing to a sub-directory of the user's MyDocuments folder:

```
String.Format("{0}\XML Cache", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments))
```

I understand that this setting writes an entry to the app.config file, which is XML. Is there any way to flag this value as an expression instead of a string? I would like to avoid using reflection to convert the string to an expression.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion:

```
Public Function GetCacheBaseDirectory() As String
    Dim cacheBaseLocation As String = My.Settings("XMLCacheDir")
    If cacheBaseLocation.StartsWith("#") Then ' Hm, it is a SpecialFolder
        Dim specialName As String = cacheBaseLocation.Substring(1)

        cacheBaseLocation = System.Enum.Parse(GetType(Environment.SpecialFolder), specialName)
    End If

    Return cacheBaseLocation
End Function
```

In this case, you would configure your `XMLCacheDir` setting with the value: `#MyDocuments` .

The snippet above checks if the setting value starts with `#`. If yes, it will assume your setting is pointing to a `Environment.SpecialFolder` enumeration name, and returns the directory the same way you posted above (using `Environment.GetFolderPath`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I were writing this without the need to also allow the user to reassign the cache directory, I think this would work out well. However, I want to be able to get and set the directory, and it could point to any location.

Comment: Alright, but even then my suggestion is still valid (in my point of view, hehe): You can have a Drop Down with all the `Environment.SpecialFolder` options to the user select which special folder (s)he wants to store the cache. This same  Drop Down might have a `Custom` option, which the user can then set an arbitrary directory.